# JS bind(), I need two "this" contexts

Tags: javascript, react-leaflet

This is a generic JS question.

In React-leaflet, I want to handle events via callbacks. The called function gets the caller (event) context which can be used to do stuff like this.getZoom().

```
onMoveend={this.moveend}

moveend(e){
    // e is the event target
    var zoomText = this.getZoom();
    // this.setState({zoomText: zoomText});  <-- "this" is the map object, not the my React component.
}
```

The problem is in the same time I need the react element context to update state and call other methods.

To achive "this.getZoom()" the callback should not be bound, to achive "this.setState(...)" I need to bound the callback to "this".

But how to pass both caller and callback contexts as variables to the callback?

Or may be this type of problem is solved in another way?

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nf8k23s7/1/

Comment: If I figure out how to capture the event's context, I would be able to do :  moveend.bind(eventContext, this).   and that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.target` is already the Leaflet element.

So you can use:

```
moveend(e){
    var zoomText = e.target.getZoom();
    this.setState({zoomText: zoomText});
}
```

and don't forget do bind:

```
<Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom} onMoveend={this.moveend.bind(this)}>
```

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/nf8k23s7/2/

Comment: Thanks alot! I thought I tried everything (palm face).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use => arrow function to bind this

```
moveend = (e) => {
  var zoomText = e.target.getZoom();
  this.setState({zoomText: zoomText}); 
}


<Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom} onMoveend={this.moveend}>
```

Comment: ah, that is what this "= (e) =>" ninja means :) thanks for the tip.